# Get information beyond login page in Node/Express not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

Sort of a weird situation here. I'm building a backend and frontend which talks  to a third party RESTFUL API that controls some hardware. The third party api is installed on your local system as a webserver, so to make HTTP requests you would direct them towards "localhost".

The main problem is after some changes the hardware has to be updated by logging into the webserver and clicking the "update hardware" button, this pushes all the newest changes to the actual hardware. Unfortunately the API doesn't have any default calls/commands for doing this.

After running through the files I found that I can refresh a door by simply making a GET request to`http://localhost/IntelliM/DoorsConfig/DownloadChangeForAllDoors.ashx`
If I enter this into my browser it updates the hardware perfectly.

The problem is that access to this page requires a login, which I've been trying to achieve through this code

```
/* update door */
router.get('/updatedoor', function (req, res) {
    request.post({
        headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url:     "http://localhost/IntelliM/login/index.ashx?",
        body:    "password=admin&username=admin"
    }, function(error, response, body){
        //Here is where I would make a GET request to doorupdate mentioned earlier
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

When I log the body, or have it displayed on a page, I get a large body response with most of it not really mattering besides these two lines:

```
Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" />
Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="admin" />
```

It looks like the page isn't even getting my "username" value and just returning the body of the page I would get with only the "password" input filled in.

I'm trying to get it to log the page I would normally see after logging in, because then I would know the login worked and I could then make a GET request to the page I need to.

EDIT: For context the hardware is a door controller and the changes that have to be pushed are adding a user that can access a door.

EDIT FULL BODY:

```
    <form id="loginForm" action="/IntelliM/login/login.ashx" method="post">
    <fieldset id="loginFieldSet">
            <legend id="loginFieldSetLegend">Authentication</legend>
            <div id="loginFieldSetFields">
                    <p id="loginFieldSetUsername">Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" /></p>
                    <p id="loginFieldSetPassword">Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="admin" /></p> <input type="hidden" id="ReturnUrl" name="ReturnUrl" value="/IntelliM/default.aspx" />
                    <p id="loginFieldSetButton"><input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" /></p>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="loginFormRegister">Your system is licensed for Intelli-M Access</div>
```

Comment: Try adding this way instead of body
form:    {password="admin",
username="admin"}
if worked let me know

Comment: Didn't work. I changed it to {"password":"admin", "username":"admin"} and I just get a "TypeError: First argument must be string or buffer".

Comment: If I do {password="admin", username="admin"} it doesn't work either

Comment: did you changed body to form ?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood, changed body to form with the value being {password:"admin", username:"admin"} and I still just get it only receiving the password value. Username still comes up blank

Comment: can you update the js code in the second file i.e. where <input type="text"...  lies

Comment: I don't have access to changing those files, no

Comment: open the link in browser and just copy the code before logging in that contains code on changing password field from get request.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The login page is just a simple form with the line <form id="loginForm" action="/IntelliM/login/login.ashx" method="post"> and I can't access any of the .ashx code

Comment: ok my bad i mean can you post body completely

Comment: Its very messy but sure I'll update the original post

Comment: Just added body response

Comment: you need to post login form to /IntelliM/login/login.ashx with form data as username,password, third field
ReturnUrl with value /IntelliM/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Changing index.ashx to login.ashx seemed to work, but how do I give it a return url?

Comment: If I add "ReturnURL:"/IntelliM/default.aspx" to the form object it just sends me to a page that says "object moved"

Comment: just add third parameter with user nd password

Comment: please accept answer if it worked. so it can help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change url to `/IntelliM/login/login.ashx` and add change body to

```
form: {password="admin", username="admin", ReturnURL:"/IntelliM/default.aspx"}
```